# lubuntu 12.10 amd 64bit live usb/dvd didnt worked in dell inspiron n5050 laptop

Tags: system-installation

I tried Lubuntu 12.10 live usb /dvd on my dell inspiron n 5050 laptop it didnt worked  so  but after boot screen it doesn't work only logo of Lubuntu displays on screen and then stopped. So is my hardware uncompatible or some other issue? and it doesnt boot from usb n dvd live

On my hardware open suse 12.2 x86-64 bit, ubuntu 12.04 n 12.10 64bit,linux mint cinnamon 64 bit , Debian squueze 6,scientific linux 6.3,kahel0s i686,pc bsd x64 , netrunner 12.12 amd 64 bit ,backtrack 5r3-kde 32 bit ,actually i installed on my hardware all this os just worked fine on my laptop,all worked fined but Lubuntu live dvd didnt boot on my laptop please help I really want to use it .

Right now i'm dual booting Windows 7 with mageia 2 kde x86-64 iso it works like charm..

Hardware overview

```
Processor
Intel(R) Pentium(R) CPU B940 @ 2.00GHz
Video
Intel Corporation 2nd Generation Core Processor Family Integrated Graphics Controller
Network
Atheros Communications, Inc. AR3011 Bluetooth
Network
Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8101E/RTL8102E PCI Express Fast Ethernet controller
```

The following components are contained in the Dell Inspiron 15 N5050 laptop, which has been awarded the status of Certified for Ubuntu.

```
Audio
Intel Corporation 6 Series/C200 Series Chipset Family High Definition Audio Controller
Bluetooth
Atheros Communications, Inc. AR3011 Bluetooth
Atheros Communications, Inc. AR3011 Bluetooth
CDROM
TSSTcorp DVD+-RW TS-L633J
Optiarc DVD+-RW AD-7717H
Unknown Optiarc DVD+/-RW AD-7717H
Capture
Suyin Corp. 064E:8123 (USB)
Unknown Intergrated Webcam
Disk
Generic- Multi-Card
Unknown WDC WD5000BPVT-75HXZT1
PQI PQI USB Flash Drive
ADATA ADATA USB Flash Drive
MUSHKIN MKNUFDPR2GB
Keyboard
Unknown AT Translated Set 2 keyboard
Mouse
Unknown DualPoint Stick
Unknown PIXART USB OPTICAL MOUSE
Unknown ImPS/2 ALPS GlidePoint
Network
Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8101E/RTL8102E PCI Express Fast Ethernet controller
Atheros Communications, Inc. AR3011 Bluetooth
Other
Sanyo DELL 4YRJH15
Unknown hci0
Unknown dell-wifi
Unknown i8042 KBD port
Unknown i8042 AUX port
Unknown HDA Intel PCH
Unknown Power Button
Unknown Video Bus
Unknown HDA Intel PCH HDMI/DP,pcm=3
Unknown HDA Intel PCH Mic at Ext Left Jack
Unknown HDA Intel PCH HP Out at Ext Left Jack
SCSI
Realtek Semiconductor Corp. RTS5138 Card Reader Controller
Power Quotient International Co., Ltd 3538:0901 (USB)
Kingston Technology Company Inc. 13FE:3600 (USB)
A-DATA Technology Co., Ltd. C906 Flash Drive
Touch
Unknown AlpsPS/2 ALPS DualPoint TouchPad
USB
Intel Corporation 6 Series/C200 Series Chipset Family USB Enhanced Host Controller #2
Unknown
Intel Corporation 6 Series/C200 Series Chipset Family 6 port SATA AHCI Controller
Intel Corporation 6 Series/C200 Series Chipset Family PCI Express Root Port 1
Intel Corporation 6 Series/C200 Series Chipset Family MEI Controller #1
Intel Corporation HM67 Express Chipset Family LPC Controller
PNP IBM Enhanced keyboard controller (101/2-key)
Unknown 118C:0504 (PNP)
PNP 41D0:0A08 (PNP)
PNP AT Real-Time Clock
PNP Motherboard registers
PNP ACPI Control Method Battery
PNP ACPI power button device
PNP PCI interrupt link device
PNP 41D0:0C14 (PNP)
INT 25D4:340E (PNP)
Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Pixart Imaging, Inc. Optical Mouse
Unknown 0000 (ATA_DEVICE)
Intel Corporation 2nd Generation Core Processor Family DRAM Controller
Video
Intel Corporation 2nd Generation Core Processor Family Integrated Graphics Controller
Wireless
Atheros Communications Inc. AR9285 Wireless Network Adapter (PCI-Express)
```

Comment: Please clarify your question with what the problem you have. You want to try using live cd on your laptop? But where from the vmware came into picture? Is it not working in vmware? vmware emulates your hardware, guest os doesn't run on actual hardware.

Comment: Downvoting to close due to inactivity and unlikely usefulness - Previously flagged.